# Losing work by accidental page navigation in Polymer Designer

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-designer-tool

When working in Polymer Designer if you accidentally navigate in the browser (say, via an incomplete link in your app or a gesture in Chrome) and then hit the back button all of your data is lost, reseting the canvas to the initial blank-slate template.

It looks like this happens even when you have saved your work. The URL displays the same Gist ID as before but if you try to visit the Gist via the Designer 'Share' link it has been overwritten (I'm presuming) by the new blank-slate template.

I love the idea of using Designer as a quick, visual way to work with the components you craft for an application (for example how Sales Force has shown.) The potential for using it in creating and sharing Design Systems for apps is very exciting - but this issue is a killer.

If you're running Designer locally is there a way to update the code to avoid this happening? (Either somehow saving locally or preventing it from automatically updating the Gist when you click on the share link?)

Or am I using the app with the wrong expectations - is it intended more for quick sketches and combinations of components that you then drop into a code editor? I hope not, it seems like it's very close to being a lot more.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Designer is meant for prototyping Polymer sites but is ,like the rest of the polymer project, in beta. The bad news is that like many web applications, refreshing the web page does reset your session. The good news is that Beta is the perfect time to file an issue and ask for it to be resolved. You can take note of the issue at the Designer's GitHub here:

https://github.com/Polymer/designer/issues

There is already an issue asking for them to enhance the designer with an export functionality you could add your voice to that post or create your own with the save state issue.

Comment: Good reminder, and point. Thanks, I'll follow-up there as well. My code-tweaking ambitions probably out measure my Javascript coding ability, but I wonder what it would take to update it to save to local storage instead of GitHub OR make it *not* also save the current canvas when you click on the "Share" link (going instead to the last save).